# How to set a default option value for a backbone select in wordpress media library attachment filters?

Tags: wordpress, backbone.js, media-library

Wondering if it's possible to trigger a default option for this backbone dropdown in the wordpress media library. I've created a new filter for "years", and it would be great if I could set the default to be the current year rather than always load "filter.all".

New to the world of backbone, and thanks in advance!

Here's my code that creates the filter and adds it to the toolbar.

```
// Create Years Filter
var MediaLibraryYearsFilter = wp.media.view.AttachmentFilters.extend({
    id: 'media-attachment-years-filter',

    createFilters: function() {
        var filters = {};

        filters.all = {
    
            text:  'All Years',
            props: {
                year: "",
            },
            priority: 10
        };
            
        // Get years from 2015->Today   
        this.years = function(startYear) {
            var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(), years = [];
            startYear = startYear || 1980;  
            while ( startYear <= currentYear ) {
                years.push(startYear++);
            }   
            return years;
        }
        years = this.years(2015).reverse();
        
        _.each( years || {}, function( value, index ) {
            filters[ index ] = {
                text: value,
                props: {
                    year: value
                },
                priority: 20
            };
        });
        this.filters = filters;
    }
});

// create ToolBar
var AttachmentsBrowser = wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser;
wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser = wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser.extend({    

    createToolbar: function() {
        
        // original toolbar
        AttachmentsBrowser.prototype.createToolbar.call( this );
                    
        this.toolbar.set( 'MediaLibraryYearsFilter', new MediaLibraryYearsFilter({
            controller: this.controller,
            model:      this.collection.props,
            priority: -80
        }).render() );
    },                  
});
```

Comment: I need the same functionality but I don't exactly find nothing about it. @ogdsgn did you find the solution?

Comment: So sorry I missed this @crossmax. No I never did find a solution for it. I was actually trying to use this filter to speed up the media library loading, but discovered it was actually an issue with a plugin I was using. So after fixing a bug in that plugin I didn't have a need for this anymore. Cheers!

Comment: However, I did ask Chat-GBT for fun and it came up with this bit of code. It did set the filter results as you would expect, but the dropdown selection didn't change, so that would be one issue to fix if you were to use this code. Cheers!

```   
 // Set default filter option as current year
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
filters[currentYear] = {
    text: currentYear.toString(),
    props: {
        year: currentYear.toString()
    },
    priority: 20,
    default: true // Set this filter as the default option
};

```